# World map shapefile including disputed areas

Tags: shapefile, data

I am looking for a global shapefile that allows you do show data for all disputed areas (like Waziristan, Spratlay Islands, Kahsmir, etc.). Do you have any idea where I can find a shapefile with not only the recognized countries but all disputed territories as well? Thanks a lot for any helpful input!

Stephanie

Comment: This could be quite difficult to define, I imagine most agencies such as the UN would only produce data pertaining to their member states. You could try some sources like the world bank or UNICEF, but I doubt a single perfect shapefile exists.

Comment: I know Kahsmir is one of disputed areas but is Waziristan a disputed area? Have a look on http://www.gadm.org/

Answer (score 4):

Natural Earth v2 is now available

the full list published on 18th August 2012 is here:

http://kelsocartography.com/downloads/gis/2012/natural_earth/ne_2.0.0_rc2/natural_earth_2.0.0_rc2_vector/

blog post on the changes
http://kelsocartography.com/blog/?p=4246

300mb zip file is available - http://kelso.it/x/ne2rc2v0 [direct link]

disputed areas might not be how you have envisioned - it depends on the original source
There are over 200 in total across the world

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes

Answer (score 1):

The Cshapes map might be of some use to you. It doesn't show disputed areas per se but does have historical boundary changes:

http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes/shapefile

Digging further into Nils' site there is also the [WarViews Project](http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/warviews) which also links to the [International Conflict Research](http://www.icr.ethz.ch/research/warviews) page which may be better maintained.

This is assuming all disputed territories are being fought over.

Please add a link of what you're doing. I'd be interested to see the results.