# Vector Data for Disputed Island Areas (Paracel and Spratley Islands)?

Tags: data

I am looking for a free vector data set for the Paracel and Spratley Island archipelagos.

Natural Earth, [suggested on StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34212/world-map-shapefile-including-disputed-areas), does not include these features, due to their small size.

Has anyone seen such a layer, ideally including island names?

My interest is not in their sovereignty, but rather in showing their location and potentially spatial relationship with coral reefs. As such, data could be in any language (although English is preferred). Other island groups in the region are easy to find, but these two seem to be "missing" from many data sets because they are not assigned to any one country.

Comment: Under what License do you need this data? These Islands seem to be there on OSM.

Comment: OSM license works. Thank you for reminding me of this resource. I would have usually looked there, but it slipped my mind this time.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe your comment is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest that you have a look at the OpenStreetMap Database.

OSM definitely contains these islands.

If you try to download them from a source like [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html), you should know that some of them have been marked as Chinese while others have been shown as a part of Philippines. You can download the data for both these countries and check whether they contain what you require.

Otherwise you could also try to export them from [bbike](http://extract.bbbike.org/)